# Laravel Eloquent: Count Rows and group them by the day

Tags: laravel, group-by, eloquent, php-carbon

I have a Model called "AdInteraction", these interactions can either be a `click` or a `view` (They either have boolean `clicked` or boolean `viewed` set to true).

Along every Interaction I save the `created_at` date.

Now this is what I want to end up with in order to have all the data I need to populate a ChartJS Chart:

```
[
    {
        "date": "01-01-2018"
        "clicks": 13,
        "views": 25
    },
    {
        "date": "02-01-2018"
        "clicks": 25,
        "views": 74
    },
    {
        "date": "03-01-2018"
        "clicks": 0,
        "views": 0
    },
]
```

This is a query I already got on my `Ad` model which is related to `AdInteraction`:

```
public function getClicksForLastDays()
{
    return $this->clicks()->get()->groupBy(function($date) {
        return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('y-m-d');
    });
}
```

However this returns me an array of arrays looking like this:

[image]

What would be the correct and most efficient way to fetch the clicks and count them by days?

Comment: Using `date` as column name is not a good idea as it is a [reserved word in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) (and probably every other SQL type).

Comment: Date is not the column name only the name I chose for the array value. The column name is `created_at` @Namoshek

Comment: Sure, sorry, should've looked a second time at the picture of your output.

Answer (score 2):

try this and let me know, I assume your column names are `date,clicks,views`, if its different then pls let me know, so I will adjust the answer or you can do it your self..

```
  AdInteraction::select([DB::raw('DATE(date)'),DB::raw('count(case when clicks ="true" then 1 end) as "Clicks"'),
DB::raw('count(case when views ="true" then 1 end) as "Views"')])
->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE(date)'))
->get();
```

or try this

```
 AdInteraction::select([DB::raw('DATE(date)'),DB::raw('count(case when clicks =true then 1 end) as "Clicks"'),
        DB::raw('count(case when views =true then 1 end) as "Views"')])
        ->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE(date)'))
        ->get();
```

Comment: You might wanna group by `DATE(date)` as `date` seems to be a datetime. Otherwise, looks good (at least for some SQL types).

Comment: Thanks! I adjusted it like this: https://pastebin.com/tL6NcaSZ, this gives me a few arrays like this: https://pastebin.com/E1719t11. The only problem here is that it takes the time into account to when groupng. However I want to group by day-month-year and ignore the time. I also want it to show the last 30 days even if there are no clicks or views it should produce an array with the date and `clicks ` & `views` set to 0. Do you know how I can do this?

Comment: yes you are correct, if its a datetime column, then he has to use `->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE(date)'))` , however he mentioned as date type in his questions.

Comment: and yes you can show 30 days, for that you need to have a database table containing all days of the month, so you can write a crone job to fill this for entire year, 
and follow my this tutorial (for another scenario) on how to adjust it for your case, 
https://www.techalyst.com/links/read/137/laravel-data-visualization-chart-vuejs-data-visualization-chart-periodical-sales-analytic-chart

and if you need further helps write to me in my blog and I will answer you.. regards

Comment: Alright got it now. I needed to use sum() in the SQL query instead of count(). Works perfect now!

Comment: ok good, you can use either `sum` or `count` in this case, I hope you got the same result with the `count` as well, unless the value is something like quantity or price etc...

Answer (score 1):

You should consider abandoning the idea of grouping by `date` using `datetime` column since such query will be very inefficient. When you, for example, `GROUP BY DATE(created_at)` MySQL will be performing this cast function for each row and won't be able to utilize indexes for `created_at`.

Therefore I recommend you to denormalize your table by introducing separate `DATE created_date_at` column for `created_at` value and create an index for it. Then you will be able to efficiently group your stats by this new column value. Just be sure to register the following code for your model:

```php
AdInteraction::creating(function ($adInteraction) {
    $adInteraction->created_date_at = $adInteraction->created_at->format('Y-m-d');
});
```

Or you can consider creating separate `int` columns for year, month and day. Then you can create a multi-column index and group by these columns. This way you will be able to also easily retrieve stats by days, months and years if needed.